# What are the options for a db user instead of 'root'

Tags: php, database, authentication

So I created a registration and login system and for now everyone who would connect would conenct as root. I know thats not good as they get full access. So my question what are alternatives and how do I create them or where can I find some. 
Thanks to everybody ahead.

Comment: Do you mean you're creating actual database users (e.g. in the `mysql.user` table assuming MySQL/MariaDB) ... or is it users on your application? It *sounds* like you're attempting the former but that seems unlikely...

Comment: That "everyone" should only be *your application*. Users have no direct access to the database (right?!), so they cannot do anything that your application isn't programmed to do. That's where the permission limitations are for your users. It *may* make sense to also limit the capabilities of your application towards the database, but that's (hopefully) a separate topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't be a big problem (although not recommended), that your php app uses the "root" user of a database, as long as you sanitize user input well enough.

But for extra safety, the standard is to create a database user for every app, and grant just the neccessary permissions. You didn't specifiy the type of database you're using, so I'm going to give an example for MySQL and Postgresql.

MySQL:

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name.* TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Postgresql:

```
CREATE USER newuser WITH PASSWORD 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE database_name TO newuser;
```